# Conversion InnoDB fail. ERROR 1114 The table is full

Tags: mysql

I have a conversion problem with a table on the 240.
An `ALTER TABLE db_logs ENGINE = INNODB;`
who gives me

```
Errors during migration from MyISAM to InnoDB ...
```

I see the error `SQL Error (1114): The table '# sql-667e_61' is full`.

This table has 60,000 rows and is 7.8 GB.
The conversion goes up to the line 30 000!

Other tables less than 3GB are converted without problems.

I tried to create a blank identical table `db_logs_innodb` and then insert them from the same problem db_logs table even putting an `autocommit = 0` before the insert.

I looked at the values `innodb_file_per_table` data on some mailing lists but I do not find this variable.
I do not have an `innodb_data_file_path` variable

No full partition. Not tied to the file system.

Ideas ??

Comment: Hello,
in fact the conversion takes almost double the file system used in Myisam!

So you have to plan big !!

Moreover for tables of more than 5 GB the ALTER TABLE xxx ENGINE = INNODB does not work!

We have to do :
Code: Select All - View in a separate window

Then:
SHOW CREATE TABLE db_logs \ G
Copy and paste the answer and change db_logs to db_logss
set autocommit = 0;
INTO INSERT db_logss SELECT * FROM db_logs ORDER BY id;
commit;
DROP TABLE db_logs;
ALTER TABLE db_logss RENAME db_logs;

Answer (score 1):

More safe way is to create empty table, change engine, copy data from current one and rename table names:

```
CREATE TABLE db_logs_new LIKE db_logs;

ALTER TABLE db_logs_new ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO db_logs_new SELECT * FROM db_logs; 

ALTER TABLE db_logs RENAME db_logs_old;

ALTER TABLE db_logs_new RENAME db_logs;
```

and if everything is ok and You want to destroy old table:

```
DROP TABLE db_logs_old;
```

Comment: U have misstype in answer `db_logs_tmp` is actual `db_logs_new`